# How can I invert? a coordinate space?

Tags: geometry, 2d, coordinates

Here's a problem that's been wrecking my brain for a while.

Given:
  I have two coordinate spaces:
    the global space G, and
    a local space A, and
  I know the position and rotation of A relative to G.

Question:
  How can I programmatically calculate the position and rotation of G relative to A?

On graph paper, I can calculate this by hand:

- if A relative to G is (4, 1) 90deg, then G relative to A is (-1, -4) -90deg
- if A relative to G is (5, 0) 0deg, then G relative to A is (-5, 0) 0deg

... but I'm having trouble transferring this calculation to software.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes

Comment: construct 4x4 homogenous matrix representing the transform from G to A and just invert it ....see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075743/how-do-i-compose-a-rotation-matrix-with-human-readable-angles-from-scratch/28084380?s=1|67.5068#28084380)

Answer (score 0):

In matrix form,

```
y = R x + t
```

where `R` is the rotation matrix and `t` the translation of the origin.

The reverse way,

```
x = R' (y - t) = R' y + (- R' t)
```

where `R'` is the inverse of `R`, and also its transpose.